# Unable to determine VOB for pathname

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm a new ClearCase user (woe is me...), on a Linux machine; I've been told to create a new branch time (to check my changes into), as preparation to creating my own view in which I'll make edits.

So, I ran

```
$ct mkbrtype foo -c "this is my new branch type"
```

to create my branch type. But - this gives me:

```
ct: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
```

My questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Do I need to create the view first? create and `ct setview` into it? Or - something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving to the folder where your VOBs are mounted, e.g.

```
$ cd /path/to/vobs/
$ ct mkbrtype foo -c "this is my new branch type"
Created branch type "foo".
```

Hopefully that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Hopefully that should be sufficient.

In addition of [`mkbrtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm),here is what a dedicated view (dynamic if you want) would look like.
Simply modify your config spec for that new view with the right rules using your new branch: any new checkout will create the branch (`mkbranch`) automatically at the next checkout within that view.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../myBranch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch myBranch
element * /main/0 -mkbranch myBranch
element * /main/LATEST
```

Since you will do the checkout within  `/path/to/vobs/viewtag/path/to/file`, you will be in the right vob for the branch to be created.

Comment: @einpoklum All right, I have amended the answer accordingly. This is for other readers to understand how the config spec will use the branch type you have just created.